# ASP.Net scripts isn't loading

Tags: asp.net, web, iis-express

I have a problem with my Scripts in my Web-Application. I work about an local Website with ASP.net and IIS Express. But the Scripts doesn´t load correctly.

[Css and js Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgWZO.jpg)

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6TxZ.png)

Comment: Can you please provide Code of the Class/Method where you are trying to load your scripts? Use the code tags, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Error is 404(not found). that mean js url path on your solution not correct.
to solve it:
Drag any JS file from solution explore and drop it into aspx page html. then replace all js files paths exists on the same directory with the new path without name of js file name